# I want to get the ping execution time and result in string after ping host

Tags: java, ping

I want to get the ping execution time and result in string after ping host. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
boolean isPinged = InetAddress.getByName(servername).isReachable(2000); // 2 seconds
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime;
if(isPinged) {
    System.out.println("pinged successfully in "+ currentTime+ "millisecond");
} else {
    System.out.println("PIng failed.");
}
```

But this will use ICMP ping only in windows system.

Answer (score 0):

did you check this 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Ping.java

and

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.net/InetAddressisReachableinttimeout.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long ping;




String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "ping 192.168.1.101" };
commandProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader buffy = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandProcess.getInputStream()));
String readline;
while((readline = buffy.readLine())!=null){
System.out.println(readline);
if(readline.contains("reply")){
 long ping = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("Pinged in:"+ ping);
 }
}
 long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
 String done = "Completed in times:" +start + ping +end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used it -

```
private static void checkPing(String hostName) {

    String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "ping " + hostName };
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String readline;
        while ((readline = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            if (readline.contains("Reply")) {
                System.out.println("Pinged " + hostName + " in : "
                        + readline.substring(readline.indexOf("time=") + 5, readline.indexOf("ms")) + " ms");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Gives you the exact (reliable) ping latency in milliseconds for each ping request.
You can then add the four of them, if required