# java how to measure delay between server and clients

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I have an android app that I want to send some commands(usually integer) to some clients (they're also in java andoid) . thing that is important is measuring the delay time between send command and recieving the message(in client). the app will share the current time of a music to all clients and they should play it so Simultaneous (to be is sync!!). what's your Idea about this?

Thank You again :)

Comment: Store send-time before sending, send send-time along with whatever. Store receive-time on receiver end. Compare send-time with receive-time

Comment: You can try to [define the ping time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8816971/668148) between the client and the server.

Comment: @bpgeck the app is on android platform so the server's time and client's time is not surely the same!! every second is impportant

Comment: You don't calculate it. You *measure* it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's hard with that, get **current timestamp** *(1)* (in millis) before sending your request and get current timestamp *(2)* when you receive a response from the server.

Then do `(2) - (1)` and you'll have your delay.

But many factors need to be handle like network signal strenght.

Comment: app is on android platform so the server's time and client's time is not surely the same!

Comment: Doesn't matter, all you want is the delay so you have to measure it on client side only. And the difference between client and server timestamp is : *1000.

Comment: this is round-trip time. It will almost always be different and is not accurate enough if you want to play a song by all devices at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is very difficult to achieve if not impossible. In distributed systems it is impossible to consider all clocks are in synch unless you have atomic clocks in all devices or you accept certain drift between devices.

You cannot compare a timestamp set in the server with a timestamp set in the client. Also you cannot assure all devices receive a message exactly at the same time, actually they won't.

The only way to measure the time a message takes is to determine round-trip time because in that case you are using the clock of the same node/device. Then you divide the roun-trip time by two in order to estimate the time it takes for a message to arrive destination. As you may be thinking, it is not accurate at all. Also time for a message to get destination will always differ from previous ones.

One alternative, if you accept clock drift of less than 1 sec, is to use network time protocol (NTP) to synchronize all clocks.

If you want many devices to play a song at exactly the same time, you should not rely on network time but in a different way to synchronize your devices. For example, just thinking, devices may process the sound generated by other devices and get in synch based on that (is there a patent for that?).